# ExtJS 5.0.1 populate textfield based off of combobox selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a table in my database which contains a list of Countries and their respective country codes as shown below:

```
country     country code
-------     -------------
Canada      CA
Russia      RU
USA         US
China       CN
France      FR
```

When I select the country from the combobox I would like the textfield in the form to populate its respective country code. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

My combobox is defined as below:

```
{
xtype: 'combobox',
labelAlign: 'top',
fieldLabel: 'Country',
id: 'CountrySelectField',
name: 'country_id',
store: 'Country',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
width: 300,
allowBlank:false,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the records argument to select event

```
listeners : {
      select :function  (combo, records, index, eOpts ){
        Ext.getCmp('textbox').setValue(records[0].get('country_code'))
      }
    }
```

Comment: This syntax worked! Thank you onestep. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a listener to your combobox that sets the value of your textfield like this :

```
listeners : {
      select :function  (combo, records, index, eOpts ){
        Ext.getCmp('myTextBox').setValue(combo.value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello JeroenDR - this works however it populates the textfield with the "id" of the country in the database (not the country code) - any idea how to specify it to populate the country code column instead?

Comment: You can get the rawValue of your combobox (in this case the displayField of you combo) by changing it to :

Ext.getCmp('myTextBox').setValue(combo.getRawValue());

Comment: That will populate the textfield with the same value as the combobox. What I would like is the textfield to populate with the value of the countrycode associated to the country. So in the database each country has 3 things associate with it - id, name, country_code. id is generated dynamically everytime a new entry goes into the DB (incrementing integers), name is being selected in the combobox but I would like the textfield to populate with the country_code. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can set the value based on the records it's passing you in the select function. So you should be able to set it by changing that line into :

Ext.getCmp('myTextBox').setValue(records[0].data.country_code);

Does that work?

Comment: Ext.getCmp('countryCode').setValue(records[0].data.country_cod‌​e); returns "illegal character" in my console

Comment: Try putting a debugger in the first line of your select listener and see if you can find the needed value in records. But based on the structure you described it should be under records[0].data.country_code.